# How to set visible posts by js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have issue that I need some helps.

For example, I have HTML like:

```
<div class="posts">
   posts 1
</div>
<div class="posts">
   posts 2
</div>
<div class="posts">
   posts 3
</div>
<div class="posts">
   posts 4
</div>
```

Now, I want use Javascript/Jquery to make the number of post is visible or not.

Example: if i use js like this then 3 posts is visible, the fourth post... is invisible.

```
<script>
numbervisible = "3"
</script>
```

How can I do this with Js/jquery. Thanks.

Comment: **element.style.display**

Comment: @undone: please give your answer below. tks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the jquery tag,  but @blackSheep's answer is the way to do it!

Comment: @happi: Check jsFiddle below in the edit of BlackSheep's answer.

Comment: look into mvvm type js frameworks, e.g. [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), where you don't need to worry about such a stuff.

Comment: @skmasq Using a library just for showing/hiding elements can be overkill, for this purposes using vanilla JavaScript is a better option.

Comment: @BlackSheep I'm just suggesting something for the long run, surely this isn't the only problem in OP project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `slice()` method:

```
$('.posts').hide().slice(0, numbervisible).show();
```

And here is a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H7aTs/

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a jQuery psuedo selector

```
<script>
numbervisible = '3';
$('.posts:gt(' + (numbervisible -1) +  ')').hide();
</script>
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77NQs/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference posts by specific ID # and not just position in list:

```
<div id="posts_1">
   posts 1
</div>
<div id="posts_2">
   posts 2
</div>
<div id="posts_3">
   posts 3
</div>
<div id="posts_4">
   posts 4
</div>
```

then:

```
$("#posts_" + post_no).hide();
$("#posts_" + post_no).show();
$("#posts_" + post_no).toggle();
```

etc.

Comment: This is such a bad practice.